# How to solve team provision issue without giving someone login information?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Sometimes, other team members receive certificates and provision files from me.

And it is finely installed but, 'team ID' warning is shown sometime.

When they login to ADC account in xcode (by clicking 'fix issue' button on xcode) it is solved.

But, some developers are from other team/company, so it is hard to tell them login information.

In this case, how to solve team provision (team prefix) problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply (I say simply, but if can be one of the most aggravating parts of iOS development) need to make sure you are providing the developers with the private key for the certificate, the certificate, and provisioning profile for development.  If your project settings are correct, you should not get the team prefix problem.  Also, I would encourage the other team members to delete all their other certificates and profiles before installing yours.

The other option would be to add their Apple IDs to your account as a team member.  They can have their own credentials, but still access the account through xCode.